# Jquery: <select> with images, having trouble to handle response of two <select> separate

Tags: html, jquery, css

I am using online jquery to handle images in "select" element of HTML. But now I am facing trouble separating events on each "select" element.

```js
var selectedId = "";
      var langArray = [];
      $(".box").each(function () {
        selectedId = $(this).attr("id");
        $(this)
          .find(".vodiapicker option")
          .each(function () {
            var img = $(this).attr("data-thumbnail");
            var text = this.innerText;
            var value = $(this).val();
            var item =
              '<li><img src="' +
              img +
              '" alt="" value="' +
              value +
              '"/><span>' +
              text +
              "</span></li>";
            langArray.push(item);
          });

        $(this).find("#a").html(langArray);

        //Set the button value to the first el of the array
        $(this).find(".btn-select").html(langArray[0]);
        $(this).find(".btn-select").attr("value", "en");
      });
      //change button stuff on click
      $("li").click(function () {
        var img = $(this).find("img").attr("src");
        var value = $(this).find("img").attr("value");
        var text = this.innerText;
        var item =
          '<li><img src="' + img + '" alt="" /><span>' + text + "</span></li>";
        $(".btn-select").html(item);
        $(".btn-select").attr("value", value);
        $(".b").toggle();
        //console.log(value);
      });

      $(".btn-select").click(function () {
        $(".b").toggle();
      });

      //check local storage for the lang
      var sessionLang = localStorage.getItem("lang");
      if (sessionLang) {
        //find an item with value of sessionLang
        var langIndex = langArray.indexOf(sessionLang);
        $(".btn-select").html(langArray[langIndex]);
        $(".btn-select").attr("value", sessionLang);
      } else {
        var langIndex = langArray.indexOf("ch");
        $(".btn-select").html(langArray[langIndex]);
        //$('.btn-select').attr('value', 'en');
      }
```

```css
      .vodiapicker {
        display: none;
      }

      #a {
        padding-left: 0px;
      }

      #a img,
      .btn-select img {
        width: 18px;
      }

      #a li {
        list-style: none;
        padding-top: 5px;
        padding-bottom: 5px;
      }

      #a li:hover {
        background-color: #f4f3f3;
      }

      #a li img {
        margin: 5px;
      }

      #a li span,
      .btn-select li span {
        margin-left: 30px;
      }

      /* item list */

      .b {
        display: none;
        width: 100%;
        max-width: 350px;
        box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.175);
        border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
        border-radius: 5px;
      }

      .open {
        display: show !important;
      }

      .btn-select {
        margin-top: 10px;
        width: 100%;
        max-width: 350px;
        height: 34px;
        border-radius: 5px;
        background-color: #fff;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
      }

      .btn-select li {
        list-style: none;
        float: left;
        padding-bottom: 0px;
      }

      .btn-select:hover li {
        margin-left: 0px;
      }

      .btn-select:hover {
        background-color: #f4f3f3;
        border: 1px solid transparent;
        box-shadow: inset 0 0px 0px 1px #ccc;
      }

      .btn-select:focus {
        outline: none;
      }

      .lang-select {
        margin-left: 50px;
      }
```

```html
<script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"
      integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4="
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
<div class="box" id="one">
      <select class="vodiapicker">
        <option>Select one</option>
        <option value="en" class="test" data-thumbnail="images/3.png">
          English
        </option>
        <option value="au" data-thumbnail="images/3.png">Engllish (AU)</option>
      </select>

      <div class="lang-select">
        <button class="btn-select" value=""></button>
        <div class="b">
          <ul id="a"></ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box" id="two">
      <select class="vodiapicker">
        <option>Select one</option>
        <option value="en" class="test" data-thumbnail="images/3.png">
          french
        </option>
        <option value="au" data-thumbnail="images/3.png">french F</option>
      </select>

      <div class="lang-select">
        <button class="btn-select" value=""></button>
        <div class="b">
          <ul id="a"></ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

When I click on a select element, both are opening and plus, the content on HTML is separate for both div, but when I click on select dropdown two, it shows the content of one as well.

Comment: As these are new elements, it wold be best to use Delegate click event call. Like `$("ul").on("click", "li", function(event){ })`. You might also save a lot of time by looking at jQuery UI Selectmenu: https://jqueryui.com/selectmenu/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it,

You might want to change the image on the button and use ccs to add it as it block the click of the button because its effectively on top o it as is the text,

```js
$(function() {
  $(".box").each(function() {
    let selectedId = "";
    let langArray = [];
    selectedId = $(this).attr("id");
    $(this)
      .find(".vodiapicker option")
      .each(function() {
        let img = $(this).attr("data-thumbnail");
        let text = this.innerText;
        let value = $(this).val();
        let item =
          '<li><img src="' +
          img +
          '" alt="" value="' +
          value +
          '"><span>' +
          text +
          "</span></li>";
        langArray.push(item);
      });

    $(this).find("#a").html(langArray);
    //Set the button value to the first el of the array
    $(this).find(".btn-select").html(langArray[0]);
    $(this).find(".btn-select").attr("value", "en");
  });
  $(document).click(function() {
    if ($(event.target).is("button.btn-select") === false) {
      $(".box").each(function() {
        if ($(this).find(".b").is(':visible')) {
          $(this).find(".b").toggle();
        }
      })
    }
  })
  //change button stuff on click
  $("li").click(function() {
    let img = $(this).find("img").attr("src");
    let value = $(this).find("img").attr("value");
    let text = this.innerText;
    let item =
      '<li><img src="' + img + '" alt="" /><span>' + text + "</span></li>";
    $(this).parents("div.lang-select").find(".btn-select").html(item);
    $(this).parents("div.lang-select").find(".btn-select").attr("value", value);
    $(this).parents("div.lang-select").find(".b").toggle();
    //console.log(value);
  });

  $(".btn-select").click(function() {
    $(this).parents("div.lang-select").find(".b").toggle();
    if (($(this).parents("div, .box")[1].id === "two") &&
      ($("#one").children("div.lang-select").find(".b").is(':visible'))) {
      $("#one").children("div.lang-select").find(".b").toggle();
    } else if (($(this).parents("div, .box")[1].id === "one") &&
      ($("#two").children("div.lang-select").find(".b").is(':visible'))) {
      $("#two").children("div.lang-select").find(".b").toggle();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.vodiapicker {
  display: none;
}

#a {
  padding-left: 0px;
}

#a img,
.btn-select img {
  width: 18px;
}

#a li {
  list-style: none;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}

#a li:hover {
  background-color: #f4f3f3;
}

#a li img {
  margin: 5px;
}

#a li span,
.btn-select li span {
  margin-left: 30px;
}


/* item list */

.b {
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 350px;
  box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.175);
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.open {
  display: show !important;
}

.btn-select {
  margin-top: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 350px;
  height: 34px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.btn-select li {
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
}

.btn-select:hover li {
  margin-left: 0px;
}

.btn-select:hover {
  background-color: #f4f3f3;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0px 0px 1px #ccc;
}

.btn-select:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.lang-select {
  margin-left: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="box" id="one">
  <select class="vodiapicker">
    <option>Select one</option>
    <option value="en" class="test" data-thumbnail="images/3.png">
      English
    </option>
    <option value="au" data-thumbnail="images/3.png">Engllish (AU)</option>
  </select>

  <div class="lang-select">
    <button class="btn-select" value=""></button>
    <div class="b">
      <ul id="a"></ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="box" id="two">
  <select class="vodiapicker">
    <option>Select one</option>
    <option value="en" class="test" data-thumbnail="images/3.png">
      french
    </option>
    <option value="au" data-thumbnail="images/3.png">french F</option>
  </select>

  <div class="lang-select">
    <button class="btn-select" value=""></button>
    <div class="b">
      <ul id="a"></ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I hope this helps

Comment: I have use this `$(document).mouseup(function (e) {
        var container = $(".dropdown"); // Give you class or ID

        if (
          !container.is(e.target) && // If the target of the click is not the desired div or section
          container.has(e.target).length === 0
        ) {
          // ... nor a descendant-child of the container
          container.css("display", "none");
        }
      });` this works better for me, so if I have more than ten "select" elements.  conditional programming will not help me much.

Comment: if that works for you then its good that you were able to come up with your own solution i hope i was able to help still

Answer (score 1):

I think this should work for you

```js
$(".box").each(function() {
  let selectedId = "";
  let langArray = [];
  selectedId = $(this).attr("id");
  $(this)
    .find(".vodiapicker option")
    .each(function() {
      let img = $(this).attr("data-thumbnail");
      let text = this.innerText;
      let value = $(this).val();
      let item =
        '<li><img src="' +
        img +
        '" alt="" value="' +
        value +
        '"/><span>' +
        text +
        "</span></li>";
      langArray.push(item);
    });

  $(this).find("#a").html(langArray);
  //Set the button value to the first el of the array
  $(this).find(".btn-select").html(langArray[0]);
  $(this).find(".btn-select").attr("value", "en");
});
//change button stuff on click
$("li").click(function() {
  let img = $(this).find("img").attr("src");
  let value = $(this).find("img").attr("value");
  let text = this.innerText;
  let item =
    '<li><img src="' + img + '" alt="" /><span>' + text + "</span></li>";

  $(this).parents("div.lang-select").find(".btn-select").html(item);
  $(this).parents("div.lang-select").find(".btn-select").attr("value", value);
  $(this).parents("div.lang-select").find(".b").toggle();
  //console.log(value);
});

$(".btn-select").click(function() {
  $(this).parents("div.lang-select").find(".b").toggle();
});
```

```css
.vodiapicker {
  display: none;
}

#a {
  padding-left: 0px;
}

#a img,
.btn-select img {
  width: 18px;
}

#a li {
  list-style: none;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}

#a li:hover {
  background-color: #f4f3f3;
}

#a li img {
  margin: 5px;
}

#a li span,
.btn-select li span {
  margin-left: 30px;
}


/* item list */

.b {
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 350px;
  box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.175);
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.open {
  display: show !important;
}

.btn-select {
  margin-top: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 350px;
  height: 34px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.btn-select li {
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
}

.btn-select:hover li {
  margin-left: 0px;
}

.btn-select:hover {
  background-color: #f4f3f3;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0px 0px 1px #ccc;
}

.btn-select:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.lang-select {
  margin-left: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="box" id="one">
  <select class="vodiapicker">
    <option>Select one</option>
    <option value="en" class="test" data-thumbnail="images/3.png">
      English
    </option>
    <option value="au" data-thumbnail="images/3.png">Engllish (AU)</option>
  </select>

  <div class="lang-select">
    <button class="btn-select" value=""></button>
    <div class="b">
      <ul id="a"></ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="box" id="two">
  <select class="vodiapicker">
    <option>Select one</option>
    <option value="en" class="test" data-thumbnail="images/3.png">
      french
    </option>
    <option value="au" data-thumbnail="images/3.png">french F</option>
  </select>

  <div class="lang-select">
    <button class="btn-select" value=""></button>
    <div class="b">
      <ul id="a"></ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I hope this helps

Comment: you are awesome you saved me...$(this).parents("div.lang-select").find(".btn-select").html(item); this is very important

Comment: glad I was able to, as an FYI if you debug the js and use $(this).parents() it will give you a list from which you can select the parent item that has  the child element within it that you want to find ;) :)

Comment: any idea how I supposed to close the "<select>" when it clicked outside the dropdown and if one is open previous one should close too.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following.

```js
$(function() {
  function convertSelect(target) {
    var opts = $("option", target);
    var container = $("<div>", {
      class: "ui-selectmenu"
    }).insertAfter(target);
    // Move original inside container
    $(target).detach().appendTo(container).hide();

    var list = $("<ul>", {
      class: "ui-selectmenu-list collapsed"
    }).appendTo(container);
    opts.each(function(i, o) {
      // Make List Option
      $("<li>", {
        class: "ui-selectmenu-option"
      }).data("value", $(o).val()).html("<span>" + $(o).text() + "</span>").appendTo(list);
      // Select Original selected item
      if ($(o).is(":selected")) {
        $("li:last", list).addClass("selected");
      }
      // Add Thumbnail, if present
      if ($(o).data("thumbnail") != undefined) {
        $("li:last span", list).before("<img src='" + $(o).data("thumbnail") + "' alt='" + $(o).val() + "' />");
      }
    });

    if ($(".selected", list).length == 0) {
      // Default to Item 0 if none is selected in Original
      $("li", list).eq(0).addClass("selected");
    }
    // Psudeo Collapse
    $("li:not('.selected')", list).hide();

    $("li", list).click(function(event) {
      if ($(this).hasClass("selected") && list.hasClass("collapsed")) {
        // Exapnd Menu
        list.removeClass("collapsed");
        $("li", list).show();
        return false;
      }
      if ($(this).hasClass("selected") && !list.hasClass("collapsed")) {
        // Same Item selected, collapse
        $("li:not('.selected')", list).hide();
        list.addClass("collapsed");
        console.log("Selected", $(".selected", list).data("value"));
        return false;
      }
      // Menu Expanded, new Item selected
      $(".selected", list).removeClass("selected");
      $(this).addClass("selected");
      $("li:not('.selected')", list).hide();
      list.addClass("collapsed");
      console.log("Selected", $(".selected", list).data("value"));
    });
  }

  $(".vodiapicker").each(function() {
    convertSelect(this);
  });

  /*
  // localStorage not support in Snippet
    //check local storage for the lang
    var sessionLang = localStorage.getItem("lang");
    if (sessionLang) {
      //find an item with value of sessionLang
      var langIndex = langArray.indexOf(sessionLang);
      $(".btn-select").html(langArray[langIndex]);
      $(".btn-select").attr("value", sessionLang);
    } else {
      var langIndex = langArray.indexOf("ch");
      $(".btn-select").html(langArray[langIndex]);
      //$('.btn-select').attr('value', 'en');
    }
    */
});
```

```css
.ui-selectmenu {
  background: #fff;
  width: 350px;
}

.ui-selectmenu-list {
  padding-left: 0px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  z-index: 1001;
}

.ui-selectmenu-list li {
  background: #fff;
  list-style: none;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
}

.ui-selectmenu-list li:hover {
  background-color: #f4f3f3;
}

.ui-selectmenu-list li img {
  width: 18px;
  margin: 5px;
}

.ui-selectmenu-list li span {
  margin-left: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<select class="vodiapicker">
  <option>Select One</option>
  <option value="en" class="test" data-thumbnail="images/3.png">English</option>
  <option value="au" data-thumbnail="images/3.png">Engllish (AU)</option>
</select>

<select class="vodiapicker">
  <option>Select One</option>
  <option value="en" class="test" data-thumbnail="images/3.png">french</option>
  <option value="au" data-thumbnail="images/3.png">french F</option>
</select>
```

This works as you described. It also uses jQuery to hide the Select elements and build all the needed elements for a Select Menu with Images.